# MS Project - Scheduled Gap in Resource Time

Tags: scheduled-tasks, microsoft-project

I have created a simple project (at this stage), but I have noticed, with automatic scheduling that MS project has left a few day 'gap' in a particular resource's scheduled time. [See image for 'Isaac':](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKWyA.jpg)

[image: 1]

I have checked constraints, holidays etc but nothing really explains why.

Any help would be appreciated. Seems a little weird that a task gets started, has 2-3 days off, then continues work on it, particularly as there are no competing tasks for that resource.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - worked it out. Turns out I must've accidentally manually changed times in a calendar along the way (have no idea how this would've happened!!!).

For others: I selected the task, go to Resource menu, select 'Clear leveling'.